Problem copying the restorepoints from backup vaults
I have been banging my head to solve this issue, there are two aws accounts 222222222222 , 777777777777 & are also inside organization. I need to do cross account copy of restore points from backup vault in 222222222222 to  vault in 777777777777 using lambda function in 222222222222 [same region - us-east-2]. The  role used by lambda is following
AWSBackupFullAccess , IAMFullAccess and custom policy below
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "backup:StartCopyJob",
                "backup:DescribeRecoveryPoint",
                "backup:ListTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:backup:us-east-2:222222222222:backup-vault:zzush-intermediate-vault-ohio"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:"
            ],
            "Resource": ""
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/",
                "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Below are the assume role contents used by lambda function
AdministratorAccess,AWSBackupFullAccess,IAMFullAccess and custom inline policy below
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:ReEncryptTo",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyPairWithoutPlaintext",
                "backup:CopyIntoBackupVault",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyPair",
                "kms:ReEncryptFrom"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:backup:us-east-2:777777777777:backup-vault:ohio-jig-vault",
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:777777777777:key/mrk-c621aa87087b4fb49d7498a0e0c07cc2"   //CMK used by ohio-jig-vault
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

below is the lambda function in 222222222222 ohio region where restorepoints are hardcoded
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    source_region = 'us-east-2'
    destination_region = 'us-east-2'
    

    source_backup_vault_name = 'zzush-intermediate-vault-ohio'
    destination_backup_vault_arn = 'arn:aws:backup:us-east-2:777777777777:backup-vault:ohio-jig-vault'
    recovery_point_arn = 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:222222222222:snapshot:awsbackup:copyjob-1ec55b91-94cf-dd7d-cfce-9470cb953973'
    iam_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/zzushBackupRole'
    

    source_backup_client = boto3.client('backup', region_name=source_region)
    destination_backup_client = boto3.client('backup', region_name=destination_region)

    try:
        response = destination_backup_client.start_copy_job(
            RecoveryPointArn=recovery_point_arn,
            SourceBackupVaultName=source_backup_vault_name,
            DestinationBackupVaultArn=destination_backup_vault_arn,
            IamRoleArn=iam_role_arn
        )
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(f"Copy job started successfully: {response['CopyJobId']}")
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error starting copy job: {str(e)}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps('Error starting copy job')
        }


The cmk kms key used in vault of 777777777777 has below policy which seems pretty relaxed
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/organizations.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/trustedadvisor.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForTrustedAdvisor",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/backup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBackup",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/mrk.kms.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForKeyManagementServiceMultiRegionKeys",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/access-analyzer.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAccessAnalyzer",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/support.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForSupport",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/ushBackupRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
                "kms:ReplicateKey",
                "kms:UpdatePrimaryRegion",
                "kms:RotateKeyOnDemand"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/organizations.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/trustedadvisor.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForTrustedAdvisor",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/backup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBackup",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/mrk.kms.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForKeyManagementServiceMultiRegionKeys",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/access-analyzer.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAccessAnalyzer",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/support.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForSupport",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/ushBackupRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/organizations.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/trustedadvisor.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForTrustedAdvisor",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/backup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBackup",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/mrk.kms.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForKeyManagementServiceMultiRegionKeys",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/access-analyzer.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAccessAnalyzer",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/aws-service-role/support.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForSupport",
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:role/ushBackupRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access from AWS Organizations accounts to copy backups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-076e27lqr9"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have enabled Cross-account backup,Backup policies and Cross-account monitoring from AWS Backup settings.
after running lambda I get the error below in lambda test
Error starting copy job: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartCopyJob operation: Insufficient privileges to perform this action.


so far i have checked the cloudtrail logs and nothing help ful have appeared apart from the same log above. Any clue what is missing here ?
